# convert a list of heterogenous django model objects to a json object

Tags: django, django-models

I have a list of Django models objects say

```
a=[obj1_mod1, obj2_mod2......objn_modn]
```

where obj1_mod1 = object 1 from model1 and so on.

Now I want to create a json object out of it which lookget all fields from model object django pythons like:

```
{"mod1":{f1_mod1:val1, f2_mod1:val2,....}
 "mod2":{f1_mod2:val1,f2_mod2:val2,....}

"modn":{f1_modn:val1, f2_modn:val2,....}
}
```

where f1_mod1 = field 1 of model 1 and corresponding val 1 = the  f1_mod1's attribute.

How to go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) lookup, which returns a dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

instance_list = [obj1_mod1, obj2_mod2 .... objn_modn]
json_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for i in instance_list:
   json_dict[unicode(i)] = i.values()

jsonified = json.dumps(json_dict)
```